# Google Analytics autotrack.js plugin url doesn't load

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to get GA's autotrack plugin (https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack) installed on my WordPress-based blog, but things didn't work out.

My code is as below:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-91255353-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('require', 'autotrack');
</script>
<script async src="http://s01.appmifile.com/stat/autotrack.js"></script>
```

and here's the url of my blog: [pickydigest.com](http://pickydigest.com)

After my research, I guess the problem is coming from the JavaScript `<script async src="http://s01.appmifile.com/stat/autotrack.js"></script>`. Why I'm saying this is that I see `No plugin url set for "autotrack".` in the GA debugger no matter how I tried to paste the code in different sequences and different ways.

Moreover, when I used the same method to install the analytics.js plugin (`<script async src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>`) as the autotrack Github page suggested, GA failed, not even sending basic pageviews.

However, I can see requests sent to autotrack.js all the time from the Chrome devtools.

I wonder if this is a specific problem to my blog, my browser or anything else,
but due to my limited knowledge of JS and other technical stuffs, I don't think I could solve this all by myself, so any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I changed the code to:

```
ga('require', 'eventTracker');
ga('require', 'outboundLinkTracker');
ga('require', 'urlChangeTracker');
......
```

It started working. I'm not quite sure why but if anyone happens to have the same problem as I do, maybe this will help. And thanks for @Sanjucta, the `ga('require', 'autotrack');` must run before pageview is sent, that's indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Move this line

```
ga('require', 'autotrack');
```

before this one :

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/display-features) says :

Note: It's important that you require the plugin after creating the tracker and before sending the pageview.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The weird thing is, when I do that, the `ga('send', 'pageview');` seems to never run. The debugger looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/vo6Kk), for the reference. Any more ideas?